# Do I need to dispose of a MessageBox or will it take care of itself?

Tags: c#, messagebox

Do I need to dispose of a MessageBox or will it take care of itself?

I have the line of code:

```
MessageBox.Show(
    message, 
    title, 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
    MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

When the user hits the OK button and the dialog box goes away is it removed from memory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`MessageBox` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx) does not implement the `IDisposable` interface, so you cannot dispose an instance.

Plus, as in your example, you are calling a static method, so there is no instance to dispose anyway.

Comment: I like it when answers do more than just answer and also teaches like this one.

Answer (score 2):

It is removed from memory...eventually. More importantly, you do not have to worry or think about it. See [Garbage Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to dispose of a MessageBox.

In fact it's not even possible to dispose a MessageBox, as it's not possible to create an instance of the class.

> "You cannot create a new instance of the MessageBox class."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to worry about here.  First off, you can't call dispose() on it because it isn't disposable.  Second, you didn't instantiate the class (you called a static method) so there's nothing for you to really dispose of anyway.